# another golang channels questions on understanding how it processes

Tags: go

I'm walking through this [blog post](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/08/24/golang-channels-explained/) to understand channels and I have a question on the [2nd example](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/08/24/golang-channels-explained/#example-2---two-single-directional-channels). I modified it a bit in the playground to [this](https://play.golang.org/p/1wX23HAn7Fg), where I'm putting more items in the channel like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    n := 3
    in := make(chan int)
    out := make(chan int)

    // We now supply 2 channels to the `multiplyByTwo` function
    // One for sending data and one for receiving
    go multiplyByTwo(in, out)

    // We then send it data through the channel and wait for the result
    in <- n
    in <- 3
    in <- 6
    in <- 10
    fmt.Println(<-out)
}

func multiplyByTwo(in <-chan int, out chan<- int) {
    // This line is just to illustrate that there is code that is
    // executed before we have to wait on the `in` channel
    fmt.Println("Initializing goroutine...")

    // The goroutine does not proceed until data is received on the `in` channel
    num := <-in

    // The rest is unchanged
    result := num * 2
    out <- result
}
```

but this throws an error:

```
Initializing goroutine...
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox639017164/prog.go:18 +0xe0

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.multiplyByTwo(0x430080, 0x4300c0)
    /tmp/sandbox639017164/prog.go:34 +0xe0
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox639017164/prog.go:14 +0xa0
```

my interpretation of this is that the channels should process data that comes in, so why would it throw an error if I'm just simply adding more to the channel? I'd assume that it would pass in the other numbers too and run those through the function as well.

if I run it like this without an out channel:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    n := 3
    in := make(chan int)
    //out := make(chan int)

    // We now supply 2 channels to the `multiplyByTwo` function
    // One for sending data and one for receiving
    go multiplyByTwo(in)

    // We then send it data through the channel and wait for the result
    in <- n
    in <- 3
    in <- 6
    in <- 10
}

func multiplyByTwo(in <-chan int) {
    // This line is just to illustrate that there is code that is
    // executed before we have to wait on the `in` channel
    fmt.Println("Initializing goroutine...")

    // The goroutine does not proceed until data is received on the `in` channel
    num := <-in

    // The rest is unchanged
    result := num * 2
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

it process the first input into the channel but then errors out again. `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Comment: `multiplyByTwo` is only receiving a single value, where do you think the other 3 values are supposed to go? (you're not putting any values "into" the channel, it holds 0 values)

Comment: so something like `in <- 3` and `in <- 6` isn't actually putting stuff in the channel?? this is where i'm confused...how do you keep putting stuff into the channel and have it process while stuff gets added

Comment: No. The channel is unbuffered, so those send operations don't store anything in the channel.

Comment: so then how does one keep "sending" stuff through the channel in this example?

Comment: You have something receiving an each item from the channel. Normally to do something more than once you would use a `for` loop. Maybe go through the official docs first, like the [Concurrency](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1) section in "Tour of Go"

Comment: Something has to receive on the other end. Every send operation should have a receive operation somewhere for the operation to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you like, think of a channel as a sort of mailbox (perhaps with special teleportation abilities, like a portal from [the game Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game))).

An *unbuffered* channel is a mailbox that has no room at all for any packages.  For someone to mail a package (send a value), they must wait until the receiver's hand pokes out of the mailbox.  They can then drop the package into the hand, which will withdraw back into the mailbox, taking the package with it.  If someone else is in line, you must get in line behind the someone-else.

A *buffered* channel is a mailbox that can hold one or more packages.  To send a package, get into the line if there is one.  When you reach the head of the line, you may look at the box.  If there is room for your package, you put it in and go on about your business.  If not, you can wait until there is room, then put the package in and go on about your business.

So there is a general pattern to send:

1. Get in line if you have to.
2. When you reach the head of the queue, put your package in if there is room, otherwise wait for room—or, for an unbuffered channel, for someone to come to the other (receive) side and put their hand in to receive.

Meanwhile, if you want to *receive* from a channel, you queue up if needed, just as for sending.  Once you're at the head of the line, you can take a package out of the box, or—for an unbuffered channel—wait with your hand sticking out of the other side of the box-with-no-room for someone to come along and put something in it.

Each goroutine is, in this analogy, like a person, or a [Go gopher](https://blog.golang.org/gopher).  It (or he or she or whatever pronoun you prefer) can queue up if needed, and put things into, or take them out of, one of these channels.  Your program starts with one goroutine, which invokes `main`.

In your code, you spin off a second goroutine, which begins at `multiplyByTwo`.  This one goroutine waits—*once*—for a number to show up in the channel, or in this case, for someone to be waiting to *send* a number since the channel is unbuffered.  It then doubles the (single) number it got, prints the result, and quits / dies / gets buried, never to exist again.

Meanwhile your `main` waits for someone to be receiving—that would be your second goroutine—until it's ready to take the number `3` that's in `n`.  That part succeeds.  Then your `main` waits for another receive so that it can send the constant `3`.

While your `main` is waiting, your other goroutine is doing its work—or maybe has finished its work—and exits.  Now there is only one "person" (or gopher or whatever) in the whole system, waiting for a second person—who does not exist and will not ever be born—to come along to take the number.  The underlying Go system can tell that this event won't ever happen, and that's when you get the message:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

(this also terminates the program).

[Burak Serdar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718768/1256452) shows how you can have your second goroutine *keep reading* numbers from the channel.  This introduces a new problem: how do you tell the second goroutine that no more numbers are coming?  The answer is that you can *close* the channel, with `close`.

If we stick with the mailbox analogy, you can think of closing the channel as putting a special sticker or label on the send side of the channel.  This prevents anyone from doing any further putting-values-in.  Any packages that are *in* the channel already are safe—they stay there until someone receives them—but no *new* packages can go in.  On the receiver side, it's easy to tell the difference between a package and this special sticker: so when you encounter the "closed" sticker, you know no more values will ever come through.  If the channel is unbuffered, you can see this sticker immediately.  If it's buffered, you'll have to take out all the existing packages first, before you can see it.

In general, the sender *should* close the channel so that receivers know they will not get anything more from it.  (In many specific cases, you can get away without closing the channel.  In particular, if the goroutine running `main` returns from its call to `main`, all the other goroutines die more or less immediately.)

Note that once closed, *no* sender can close the channel *again*, so this means that if you have a single channel that you *share* across multiple senders, only one of them can close the channel!  Making that work right is tricky, so it's more common to avoid sharing a channel across more than one writing-goroutine like this.

Answer (score 2):

The goroutine processes one value, and then terminates. You can only send the first value to your goroutine, after that, the goroutine is gone, and there's nothing listening to your channel. That's why you get deadlock, you're trying to send data to a channel where there are no listeners.

Your channels are unbuffered. That means, data exchange through the channel happens only when there is at least one listener reading from the channel, and some other goroutine writes to it.  If you create buffered channels, you can keep adding to them until the buffer is full. Otherwise, for the write operation to succeed, there must be a matching read operation.

This would work:

```
func multiplyByTwo(in <-chan int) {
    for num:=range in {
       // process num
    }
    // If here, then channel in is closed
}

in <- n
in <- 3
in <- 6
in <- 10
close(in)
// Wait for the goroutine to finish
```